# Confusion on my inductive proof of $2^n$ ≥ $n^2$ for n ≥ 4

Tags: induction

(The problem) Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove that $2^n$ ≥ $n^2$ for n ≥ 4

Here's my solution on paper (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJq7M.jpg)

(1) The Basis case is true: for n = 4 we have $2^4$  = $4^2$

(2) The Induction Step: Assume $2^k$  = $k^2$ is true for any k ≥ 4

(3) Solving for the Inductive hypothesis: I deduced that $2^k$  ≥ $k^2$ ⇒ $2(2^k$ ) ≥  $2(k^2)$ and I know that $2k^2$ ≥ $(k+1)^2$. By simplifying the binomial, I got $2k^2$ ≥ $k^2+2k+1$, now, if I subtract the left side to the right side we have $k^2-2k-1$ ≥ 0 and I also get  $1-2/k^2-1/k^2$ ≥ 0 by dividing $(1/k)^2$  . Which if you look at the bottom of my paper, inputting some values of k lead me to think that this claim isn't true.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The statement is correct, so your _proof_ is wrong somewhere. If you [edit] the question to show us your work (not an image) and tell us which parts you are unsure of we might be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If you rewrite your question using MathJax, I would look at it. The image is unreadable on my computer. Otherwise, I will vote to close...

Comment: I think you have proved that $K^2 - 2K - 1\ge 0$ for $K\ge 4$, then by following your handwritten notes backward you can prove that $2^{K+1} \ge (K+1)^2$ for $K\ge 4$. Then why did you say "the statement is not true"?

Comment: I did rewrite it with MathJax , here is the format without it Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove that :   2^n >= n^2 for n >= 4

Comment: @YoussefMohamed OK then, for $K\ge 4$, $K^2 - 2K - 1 > 0$, which implies that $K^2 - 2K - 1\ge 0$.

Comment: Your solution is not itself in MathJax. I cannot read it.

Comment: My solution is in the imgur link its a jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJq7M.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you made an error in your proof. You turned $2^{k+1}\geq(k+1)^2$ into $2k^2\geq(k+1)^2$ in the middle of the proof, which is a wrong implication. The statement you are trying to prove is true.

Secondly, even if you had made no error: failing to prove a statement is not equivalent to proving that the statement is wrong. You did not prove in any way that the statement is wrong. To do that, you would have to show that there exists a counterexample where $2^n<n^2$ for some $n\geq 4$.

Lastly, please use mathjax in the future so that your post is easily readable. Do not just photograph handwritten notes. [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: the point was if I proved that 2$k^2$ ≥$(k+1)^2$  then I proved that 2^k+1 ≥ $(k+1)^2$ as I assumed that 2^k+1  ≥ 2$k^2$

Comment: @YoussefMohamed The implication not work in the opposite direction. Proving that $2k^2\geq(k+1)^2$ is false does not prove that $2^{k+1}\geq(k+1)^2$ is false.

Comment: @YoussefMohamed Also, $2k^2\geq (k+1)^2$ is true for all $k\geq 4$. Take another look at the end of your proof, it gets quite messy.

Comment: ur right about the that the implication doesn't work in the opposite direction i'll relook at it , but the statement 2$k^2$ ≥ $(k+1)^2$ is not true as $k^2$-2k-1 equals 0 at        
k= 1-sqrt(2) or 1+sqrt(2) which are less than 4

Comment: @YoussefMohamed The statement $2k^2\geq (k+1)^2$ is true for all $k\geq 4$, which you need to prove. It does not matter what happens for $k<4$ at that point in the proof.

Comment: Bro, 2$k^2$ cannot equal $(k+1)^2$ for any value that is greater than or equal 4 that is what I mean , let me ask u the question in another way , what is the value of k that is equal than or greater than 4 that makes   2*$k^2$-$(k+1)^2$ =0

Comment: @YoussefMohamed There is no such value of $k$.

Comment: @YoussefMohamed Let me ask you the question in another way, what is the value(s) of $k$ that is equal to or greater than $4$ that makes $2k^2-(k+1)^2\ge 0$? All of those $k$s.

Comment: Ok thank u I see I forgot that it great than or equal not greater than and equal , I need to go to sleep